# modify the frequencies in a signal

Tags: numpy, scipy

I am processing an audio file and want to modify the frequencies. What I have done so far is extract the data with scipy, normalize the signal with numpy and flatten it by extracting only the first column.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import read

def modify_friquencies(audio file, x):
  #extract data
  sr, data = read("sound.wav") #read
  #normalize data
  nd = data/np.max(np.abs(data))
  #convert to mono channel
  fd = nd[:,0]
```

How might one modify the frequencies of `fd` by adding the number `x` to it?

I have tried several things. I have transformed the signal to the frequency domain and tried calculating discrete Fourier transform of a Dirac distribution centered in `x` but I feel like that just shifts the signal and doesn't really modify the frequencies. To be frank I am in over my head with Fourier transformations or dealing with complex analysis in general.

Here is the last code I tried:

```
result = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (fd + x) * np.arange(len(fd)) / sr)
```

I just got static with my first test file. As for the second test file, it seems that this also performs a signal shift.

ps: I have denormalized the data after processing and I have also returned it without performing denormalization. Here is the code for the denormalization:

```
final_result = np.max(np.abs(result)) * result
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to do [pitch scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963982/python-change-pitch-of-wav-file), i.e. changing the pitch of the signal without changing the speed of the signal. Is that right?

Comment: What do you see as the difference between a "signal shift" and a "frequency shift"? The frequencies are part of the signal. You're going to need to be more specific.

Comment: signal shift effects the time and pitch scaling works with semitones as a unit which allow less precies monupilation. I tried resampling and it seems to be what i am actually looking for. I haven't achieved the desired output yet as i am experiencing some interference. Thank you both for your inputs btw xD